# Is it possible to enforce using sudo with a command that does not need sudo?

Tags: linux, sudo

I often work with embedded Linux distributions so sometimes I have one or even more terminals with `minicom` to connect to that systems. It happened to me twice to type `reboot` in wrong console and I rebooted my host OS instead of the embedded device. I know that it was my fault and I should be more careful but I am wondering is it possible to enforce using `sudo` with a command that does not need `sudo`. I would like to have to enter a password when typing `reboot` in the console.

Comment: What system are you using that allows an unprivileged user to run `reboot`?

Comment: @Kusalananda Ubuntu 18 and Ubuntu 20.

Comment: Maybe a simple shell alias of 'reboot' that prints the hostname and asks you, if you really want to reboot the machine would suffice?

Comment: @Kusalananda almost all systems using systemd check, if there's only one real user logged in and if that's the case, he's allowed to poweroff/reboot/... the machine unprivileged.

Comment: @Kusalananda Many desktop distributions tend to have the reboot and shutdown actions available to normal users by default, for if the user cannot figure out the right way to do them, the user will be tempted to just forcefully power down the system, as the power and/or reset buttons will presumably be within easy reach...

Comment: I wouldn't complicate things with a password or such. Consider a function in your shell that prints a warning and exits. To bypass it you would deliberately use the full path to the `reboot` executable.

Comment: even if you did need extra privileges to shut the system down, it's still possible to run `sudo reboot` on the wrong system in the same way. Maybe you'd used sudo for something else and the timer hadn't yet elapsed, or maybe you had the same password on both systems (via LDAP or the old-fashioned way).

Comment: @user3333 Just wondering because none of the Ubuntu systems I have access to (18, 20 and 22) does that, but they're not desktop systems, and neither does CentOS, or any of OpenBSD, FreeBSD or NetBSD, or macOS (which _definitely_ is a desktop system).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `/usr/local/bin` is in your `PATH` before the directory that contains the `reboot` command, you could simply create a script named `/usr/local/bin/reboot` that could ask any sort of confirmation question you'd like.

For example, the script could be like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Please enter the short hostname of the system you wish to reboot:"
read REBOOTHOST
if [ "$REBOOTHOST" = "$(hostname -s)" ]
then
    # invoke the real reboot command
    exec /sbin/reboot "$@"
else
    echo "Sorry, you're in the wrong system. This is $(hostname -s)."
    echo "Please be more careful!"
fi
```

Instead of requiring you to type your password (which you by now probably could do as a spinal reflex action with no actual thinking needed), this script asks you to type in the hostname of the system you wish to reboot, and refuses to act if the entered hostname is not correct. That would enforce a cross-check between your intentions and the actual host you're entering the command in.

For a bit more rigorous implementation, you might want to study Debian's [`molly-guard` package](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/molly-guard): it provides a framework for easily implementing checks like this, and a number of ready-made checks for various situations.